# Angular 2+ content projection share data between components

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to pass some data to the nested component from parent component, can anybody help me with this, thank you

```
<parent> <nested-comp></nested-comp> </parent>
```

Comment: We would need a little more information. From the question it seems that the flow goes `parent -> nested-comp` is that correct? If so the answer you are looking for should be @Antoniossss. If not could you explain in detail what you want to do and what issues are you having?

Answer (score 1):

having

```
@Component()
class NestedComponent{

    @Input("someInput")
       private yourDataInput:any

}

<parent> <nested-comp [someInput]="someData"></nested-comp> </parent>
```

will allow you to pass data between those 2 components by setting binding `someData` into `yourDataInput` field

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, the problem here is someData exist in ParentComponent, so i can't do that.

Comment: considering your question, this is exactly the right answer to do it. what do you mean it "exists" in parent component ? of course it has to in order to be passed that way...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @Input() in Angular, for example:

In parente component html you set a label or anything you need to pass to child component:

```
private label: string = 'Label Test';
```

In parent component html you set the parameter to nested component:

```
<app-child [label]="label"></app-child>
```

In nested component ts you declare:

```
@Input() label: string;
```

In nested component html you use:

```
<label>{{label}}</label>
```

Doing this you will be able to pass any data from your parent to child components in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do that with @ViewChild. Also RxJS Subject, BehaviourSubject can be used for passing data between components(mostly for independent components)